# "sill pacote range manifest" means what?

Tags: npm

When I run `npm install`, I always see a line of `fetchMetadata: sill pacote range manifest for <pacakge name>`. What is this 'sill' mean? and what is 'pacote'? Range? Manifest?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

### sill

After reading [npmlog module source code](https://github.com/npm/npmlog) (which is used by `npm`), I believe the word `sill` come from `silly`, which means the most detail log level in `npm` install process. There are 9 levels of log in npmlog: `silent`, `error`, `warn`, `notice`, `http`, `timing`, `info`, `verbose`, `silly`.

`log.addLevel('silly', -Infinity, { inverse: true }, 'sill')`

### pacote

[pacote](https://github.com/zkat/pacote) is a module used by npm to download dependence packages metadata.

Comment: Oh the fun of open-source. nonsense naming and incomprehensible command line tools.

Comment: @JarrichVandeVoorde why not submit a pull request?